# Simple function using C pointers

Tags: c

I have the next code and I don't understand the pointer to pointer assignment in "dest" variable. Could someone please explain the meaning of this code?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
  char s1[] = "012345678";
  char dest;

  dest = *(char * ) malloc(strlen(s1));
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What in particular you don't understand?

Comment: One way to set the value of the garbage to `dest`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code doesn't make sense. It uses `malloc` to allocate memory of size 9, and then puts the first character of that allocated memory into dest. The problem is that the first character of the allocated memory can be anything, since allocated memory is not guaranteed to be initialized.

Comment: This is just an example I saw somewhere about insecure coding. What I dont understand is the pointers assignment *(char *) malloc...

Comment: This means:

1) run malloc
2) cast its result from a void pointer into a char pointer

3) use the char pointer we now have to access the char it is pointing

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
dest = *(char * ) malloc(strlen(s1));
```

will invoke undefined behavior.

### C11: 3.4.3

#### 1 undefined behavior

> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of **erroneous data**,
> for which this International Standard imposes no requirements

You are trying to dereference the uninitialized malloced memory.

Comment: -1.  This would just about be valid as a comment but isn't an answer.  Can you expand on this to say why it isn't valid?

Comment: Thanks.  Downvote removed.  Are you sure that merely dereferencing memory you have allocated results in undefined behaviour though?  A standard reference would be useful if that is the case.

Comment: @simonc; OK. Let me go through standard.

Comment: @simonc: Valgrind (memcheck) reports this as memory error, from my knowledge it's UB. For some reference see http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.uninitvals.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski valgrind is quite correct to report this as an error - the consequences of using the contents of uninitialised memory would clearly be undefined.  I'm still surprised that the mere act of reading uninitialised memory that your program clearly owns counts as UB though.  (Not saying this isn't the case, just that it'd be good to back up the assertion with a standards reference.)

Comment: @simonc; Added the reference.

Comment: @haccks: It's not undefined behavior, just arbitrary value. That's the best one can say about it though...

Comment: @Deduplicator; What does that mean ?

Comment: The behavior is defined: You read one char from that location. It is just ot meaningful, because that one is arbitrary. Now if it was a variable which could be register...

Comment: @Deduplicator; How could you say that the behavior is defined? Give me a quote from standard and I will remove my answer.

Comment: @haccks Thanks for the reference.  I'm not sure I read it the same way as you but I can see why this could imply UB.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I guess your intention is to assign a pointer to the string buffer or you may want to allocate memory then copy s1 into the newly allocated memory. The following is the right way.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  char s1[] = "012345678";

  char *dest0 = s1;                 // assign the address of s1 to dest0
  char *dest1= malloc(sizeof(s1));  // allocate memory to dest1 

  strcpy(dest1, s1);                // copy the string from s1 to dest1   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change `char dest;` by `char *dest;` and verify if char `dest != NULL` afer using malloc.
you can use strcpy to copy s1 "012345678" ===> in dest.